# Can't install Pytorch with pip by the commands provided by official website ("Could not find version ..." "No matching distribution ...")

Tags: python, pip, installation, pytorch

[image: Pytorch website]

I try to follow the instruction on [Pytorch official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and install Pytorch with **pip**. Just installed **Python 3.8.2** yesterday. My laptop is Acer Aspire 5, so I choose **None** for CUDA. Then it reports Error as **"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement..."** and **"No matching distribution for..."**

What did I do wrong? How can I install the latest **Pytorch**?

[image: error]

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: Python 3.8.2, just installed yesterday.

Comment: It doesn't look like pip uses that version. Can you check with `pip --version`, that should show the Python version that is being used. Otherwise could your try running the installation with `python -m pip`, but also verifying that `python --version` is 3.8.2.

Comment: pip 20.1 from d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

Comment: oh right... it says Python 3.8.3rc1. I downloaded Python 3.8.2 from the big button on official website at first, and then some problem occurred supposedly because it's 32-bit, and people gave me a 64-bit installer as the solution. So I re-installed Python... do you mean the command doesn't play with my Python version?

Comment: Yes, there are only very specific version available. Are you using 32-bit Windows? PyTorch doesn't have any 32-bit distributions, only 64-bit.

Comment: @MichaelJungo Thank you! I just bought this new laptop... and the Windows 10 coming with it is 64-bit, I think.